# docker cli swarm package import issues

Tags: docker, go, docker-swarm, go-modules, docker-cli

Im trying to utilise [docker/cli](https://github.com/docker/cli) client library in my own project to create/manage stacks.

I am however facing issues building the project.

---

Code below:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/docker/cli/cli/command"
    "github.com/docker/cli/cli/command/stack"
    "github.com/docker/cli/cli/flags"
)

func main() {

    cli, err := command.NewDockerCli(command.WithStandardStreams())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    cli.Initialize(flags.NewClientOptions())

    cmd := stack.NewStackCommand(cli)
    cmd.SetArgs([]string{"deploy", "--compose-file", "docker-compose.yml", "test"})

    err = cmd.Execute()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("success!")
}
```

---

I have setup a minimal go.mod:

```
module github.com/dev/test

go 1.16
```

---

When i run `go get`; i get the following errors:

```
github.com/dev/test imports
        github.com/docker/cli/cli/command/stack imports
        github.com/docker/cli/cli/command/service imports
        github.com/docker/swarmkit/api/defaults: cannot find module providing package github.com/docker/swarmkit/api/defaults
github.com/dev/test imports
        github.com/docker/cli/cli/command/stack imports
        github.com/docker/cli/cli/command/service imports
        github.com/docker/swarmkit/api/genericresource: cannot find module providing package github.com/docker/swarmkit/api/genericresource
github.com/dev/test imports
        github.com/docker/cli/cli/command/stack imports
        github.com/docker/cli/cli/command/service imports
        github.com/docker/swarmkit/api imports
        google.golang.org/grpc/transport: cannot find module providing package google.golang.org/grpc/transport
```

---

I have had a deeper look into the [docker/cli](https://github.com/docker/cli) repo and it appears that the project does not use go modules; instead its using the older `vendor` dir approach.

I was wondering how i can get the project to compile. Is there a way for `go get` to automatically reference the packages in the `vendor` directory of the imported `docker/cli` project?

Answer (score 2):

By default, the `go` command will only add the newest tagged release of a module in order to resolve a missing dependency.

According to https://github.com/docker/swarmkit/tags, the latest (and only) tagged release of `github.com/docker/swarmkit` was `v1.12.0`, back in 2016(!), and at that point in time the `api/defaults` and `api/genericresource` packages did not yet exist.

You can ask the `go` command for a newer-than-tagged version of a dependency by passing the commit hash or branch name explicitly for the version. For example, the latest commit as of when I am writing this comment is `2dcf70aafdc9ea55af3aaaeca440638cde0ecda6`, so you could pass that commit to `go get`, and it seems to build properly from that point:

```
$ go get -d github.com/docker/swarmkit/api/...@2dcf70aafdc9ea55af3aaaeca440638cde0ecda6
go: downloading github.com/docker/swarmkit v1.12.1-0.20210611195518-2dcf70aafdc9
go: downloading github.com/coreos/etcd v0.5.0-alpha.5
go: downloading github.com/gogo/protobuf v1.3.2
go: downloading github.com/docker/go-events v0.0.0-20190806004212-e31b211e4f1c
go: downloading github.com/coreos/etcd v3.3.25+incompatible
go: downloading google.golang.org/grpc v1.38.0
go: downloading github.com/golang/protobuf v1.4.2
go: downloading golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20201021035429-f5854403a974
go: downloading google.golang.org/genproto v0.0.0-20200526211855-cb27e3aa2013
go: downloading golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20200930185726-fdedc70b468f
go: downloading google.golang.org/protobuf v1.25.0
go: downloading golang.org/x/text v0.3.3
go: downloading github.com/sirupsen/logrus v1.8.1
go get: added github.com/coreos/etcd v3.3.25+incompatible
go get: added github.com/docker/go-events v0.0.0-20190806004212-e31b211e4f1c
go get: added github.com/docker/swarmkit v1.12.1-0.20210611195518-2dcf70aafdc9
go get: added github.com/gogo/protobuf v1.3.2
go get: added github.com/golang/protobuf v1.4.2
go get: added github.com/sirupsen/logrus v1.8.1
go get: added golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20201021035429-f5854403a974
go get: added golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20200930185726-fdedc70b468f
go get: added golang.org/x/text v0.3.3
go get: added google.golang.org/genproto v0.0.0-20200526211855-cb27e3aa2013
go get: added google.golang.org/grpc v1.38.0
go get: added google.golang.org/protobuf v1.25.0

$ go build github.com/docker/swarmkit/api/...

$
```

Comment: Given the above, you may want to also [file an issue](https://github.com/docker/swarmkit/issues) with the SwarmKit maintainers to request that they either explicitly tag a new (higher) release or add a `go.mod` file and [`retract`](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-file-retract) the very old existing release.

Comment: I filed https://github.com/docker/swarmkit/issues/3017 to request a fix for the upstream tagging.